# Best way to catch the end of a peak/trend on a micro timeframe?

Tags: python, plot, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm working on a project for an algo trading bot that targets crypto pumps in order to learn python and am wondering what the best stratergy would be to prevent losses by catching the end of the pump trend/peak.

The sockets I have access to is 1s OHLCV or Aggregate trade data delivered in real time here are the [socket docs](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md)

My current stratergy is to place a sell limit at a user defined multiple and then checks if the current high is lower than the previous high by a user defined percentage if so it cancels the previous limit and market sells. In backtesting this leaves me market selling the coins around 1-2 seconds after the peak.

This is my plotted chart [ppt ohlcv agg plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQG0x.jpg)

What are some other stratergies I can try? I'm a bit limited with the ohlc socket being 100ms update speed so interested in anything I could apply to the real time aggregate stream.

Comment: How do users pick their multiple that they want, and how would that always lead to identifying peaks after 1-2 seconds? This might be overfitting, so you could try to generalize this strategy more as a next step.

Comment: I ended up doing a 2 custom rolling EMAs with pandas on the aggregate trade streams in the end and cancelling the limit and market selling on the cross. But thanks for your input